# How to fix CertPathValidatorException: basic constraints check failed: this is not a CA certificate

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate

I used the openssl commands from here https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309 to create a root CA and a certifcate.

When i tried to validate the cain with the following code (chain.crt contains the root and the certifcate):

```
  @Test
  void validateChain() throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, CertPathValidatorException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
   X509Certificate root = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance(CERTIFICATE).generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("rootCA.crt"));
    byte[] basicConstraint = root.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.19");
      try(ASN1InputStream aIn = new ASN1InputStream(basicConstraint)) {
        DEROctetString octs = (DEROctetString) aIn.readObject();
        try(ASN1InputStream aIn2 = new ASN1InputStream(octs.getOctets())) {
          ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) aIn2.readObject();
          Assertions.assertTrue(BasicConstraints.getInstance(seq).isCA()); //ca on basicConstraint is set on the root certifcate
        }
      }

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Collection<? extends Certificate> certs = cf.generateCertificates(new FileInputStream("chain.crt"));
    CertPath certPath = cf.generateCertPath(new ArrayList<>(certs));
    CertPathValidator cpv = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
    List<? extends Certificate> certList = certPath.getCertificates();
    PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(certList.stream().map(certificate -> new TrustAnchor((X509Certificate) certificate, null)).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    params.setRevocationEnabled(false);
    PKIXCertPathValidatorResult result = (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult) cpv.validate(certPath, params);
  }
```

I got the following Exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: basic constraints check failed: this is not a CA certificate

    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:237)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:145)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:84)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
```

What has to be changed on the openssl settings that the validation passes a self signed certifcation chain?

Comment: Those instructions don't look correct. There is nothing there that sets the CA property. Look elsewhere. Look in the official OpenSSL documentation. Or see the comments below those instructions.

Comment: i tried this settings as well but same error:
`[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints = critical,CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = org`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be fixed when the pathlen is defined in the config file like `pathlen:1`